# Read a cell from CSV using pandas in object data type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, modbus, pymodbus

I have been working on reading a cell through Pandas. The value in the cell is actually used to read data from a Modbus device. But since Pandas is reading it as a string, I am not able to use it for processing further. Can anyone tell me how to NOT read the data as string type from the Pandas or what is the actual format/datatype to read the cells

The below shown data is what I have in my CSV and trying to read this from Pandas

```
client.read_holding_registers(0,unit=1)
client.read_holding_registers(1,unit=1)
client.read_holding_registers(2,unit=1)
```

Below is a piece of code which i am using to read the csv data

```
file = ('MB_REGISTERS.csv')
print ("Starting to read MB CSV")
sheet1 = pds.read_csv(file)
total_rows = sheet1.shape[0]
Column_address = sheet1['Sheet1']
print (Column_address)
```

Below is the output seen after running the code

```
ModbusTcpClient(127.0.0.1:502)
Starting to read MB CSV
Printing total rows
3
0    client.read_holding_registers(0,unit=1)
1    client.read_holding_registers(1,unit=1)
2    client.read_holding_registers(2,unit=1)
Name: MB_REGISTERS, dtype: object
['client.read_holding_registers(0,unit=1)'
 'client.read_holding_registers(1,unit=1)'
 'client.read_holding_registers(2,unit=1)']
Starting to read Modbus Register Address
object
```

As seen above, the cells are read as it is in string format. When I read the same value as an array directly from python code, it is working. Below is an example for the same

```
k1 = np.array([client.read_holding_registers(0,unit=1),client.read_holding_registers(1,unit=1)])
print (k1)
```

The above lines print the result as desired here

```
[<pymodbus.register_read_message.ReadHoldingRegistersResponse object at 0x0FC1ECD0>
 <pymodbus.register_read_message.ReadHoldingRegistersResponse object at 0x0F3736D0>]
```

I want the pandas to read the csv in a processable format and not in string. I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you save something to a CSV, it saves to a string. When you have code that is run like with your `k1` variable, it doesn't do that. It actually invokes the method with the applicable arguments. Either you need to invoke the method after loading it (against a properly instantiated client object) or find a work around.

Comment: Can you please suggest a work around for this ? I have tried all possible ways . The actual use case is to run an array of 30000 data at once. Iterating using for loop is take a lot of time which is not acceptable. Tried with numpy array which is again takes more time. Thus arrived at using pandas which can read all the entries at once. If you have understood the use case, please suggest me some ideas on how to go about it

Comment: Have you tried using `expr()`? eg `[ expr('client.read_holding_registers(0,unit=1)'), ...]`

Comment: @DS_London, I haven't tried that, I will check and update you

Comment: Ooops ... I meant to type `eval()`  ...

Comment: @DS_London eval() seems to be working. Thanks. Atleast I am halfway through with this option. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the joys/horrors (depending on your standpoint) of a scripting language like Python is that you can make up code on the fly, using the `eval()` function.

```
l = ['John','Graham','Michael']
strExpr = 'l[1]'
print(strExpr,'=',eval(strExpr))
```

gives a result of:

```
l[1] = Graham
```

So in this case,

```
l = ['client.read_holding_registers(0,unit=1)',
     'client.read_holding_registers(1,unit=1)',
     'client.read_holding_registers(2,unit=1)']

k1 = np.array([eval(reg) for reg in l])
```

will evaluate whatever is in the string-based expression.

EDIT: Since OP only wants to loop through items once, and assuming that `client` is already a valid object:

```
k1 = []

f = open('MB_REGISTERS.csv',mode='r')
while True:
    line = f.readline()   
    if not line:
        break
    k1.append(eval(line))

print(k1)
```

(NB. Extra checks might be needed for blank lines etc. Also it seems that eval() does not mind having the newline character at the end of the string)

Comment: I agree to your point. I was wondering if it is possible to eval the entire array at once. My whole idea was to avoid using for loop as it increases the computation time. May be if I can read like eval(l) which will apply to all the elements of the array.

Comment: @shrividyaL I suppose you could not use `read_csv()` but instead read the CSV file line-by-line from a stream without using pandas, and `append` the result of each `eval()` to a list, then pass that list to `np.array()`. That way you are only going through the items once.